# Módulos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo o seguinte erro ao tentar executar um módulo no JavaScript:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

- index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Módulos JavaScript</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- BODY -->
</body>
</html>
```

- index.js

```js
import nome from './src/config';
console.log(nome);
```

- src/config.js

```js
const nome = 'ECMAScript 6'
export default nome;
```

Porque o erro acontece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para usar um `.js` como módulo, você precisa declarar isso na tag `script`:

```
          ↓     ↓
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

Sem esse atributo, o JavaScript retorna erro em `import` ou `export`.

[Documentação sobre módulos no Google Devs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules)

Comment: Quando executo o script o seguinte erro aparece "GET http://127.0.0.1/modulos/src/config 404 (Not Found)", então adiciono a extensão ".js" do arquivo o erro some, agora eu me pergunto se é possível executar o código de import sem a extensão do arquivo?

Comment: Funciona sem extensão?

Comment: é isso que quero saber. Funciona?

Comment: Creio que não porque o navegador vai entender que é uma pasta

Comment: A extensão que define que tipo de arquivo ele é, e o navegador interpreta de forma diferente dependendo da extensão. Sem extensão é uma pasta